# splitting string with strtok to double pointer

Tags: c, strtok

```c
char **params;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    params++ = NULL;
}

int i = 0;
char* parn = strtok(all_p, " ");
           
while (parn != NULL) {
    params++ = parn;
    parn = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
            
for (int i = 0; params[i] !=NULL; i++) {
    printf("--%s--\n", *params);
}
```

I'm just trying to create a double-pointer after splitting a string/char array, where there is space.

But it's giving me an error, during compilation: **`error: expression is not assignable`**. On like `NULL` and `parn` assignment. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you allocating memory for `params`, or otherwise assigning it to point to something?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Aside from not allocating anything for `params` to point to, what I guess you're trying to do is `*params++ = NULL;`  and `*params++ = parn;`. But that will make you lose your `params` pointer (if you get it from a `malloc` call). Better is `params[i] = NULL;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `++` operator yields an *rvalue* which roughly means it can only appear on the right side of an assignment, i.e. you cannot assign to the result of that operator.

It looks like what you actually want is to assign not to `params` but what `params` points to.  So you need to dereference the result of the `++`, and that you *can* assign to:

```
*(params++)=parn;
```

You have another problem however in how you use `params`.  First, since `params` has not been initialized, attempting to dereference it (which includes array indexing) will trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and lead to a crash.  Second, you iterate through `params` multiple times without reseting it back to the beginning.

You can fix this by instead defining `params` as an array of pointers instead of a pointer to pointer, then using a temp pointer to iterate through its elements as you assign to them.

```
char * params[100] = {
  NULL
}; // initializes all element to NULL
char ** tmp = params;
char * parn = strtok(all_p, " ");
while (parn != NULL) {
  *(tmp++) = parn;
  parn = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
for (int i = 0; params[i] != NULL; i++) {
  printf("--%s--\n", params[i]);
}
```